# how to get absolute X/Y coordinates for a display object nested within Display Groups in Corona?

Tags: coronasdk

For fault finding, how can I print out the Absolute co-ordinates of a display object (e.g. image) that is buried within Display Groups? (i.e. don't want the relative position)

That is position relative to the actual display resolution, so say: Xleft, Xright, Ytop, Ybottom co-ordinates type thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup - what you're looking for is [object:localToContent()](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/objectlocaltocontent)